# The Squeeze Theorem

Tags: calculus

> Find $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(x^2\sin\frac1x\right)$$
>
> Solution:
>
> We have:
>
> $$\color{red}{-1\le\sin\frac1x\le1}\;;\;x\in(-5,5)-\{0\}\quad\text{Why?}$$
>
> (Multiplying by $x^2$ …Note that $x^2$ is non-negative)
>
> $$\implies-x^2\le x^2\sin\frac1x\le x^2\;;\;x\in(-5,5)-\{0\}$$
>
> We have
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(-x^2\right)=0=\lim_{x\to0}\left(x^2\right)$$
>
> $\implies$ By the squeeze theorem,
>
> $$\lim_{x\to0}\left(x^2\sin\frac1x\right)=0$$

Can someone please explain this problem? I could solve the ones without $\sin$/$\cos$.

Why do we assume that $\sin\dfrac1x$ is between $-1$ and $1$?

Comment: sin(x) is always between -1 and 1 ...

Comment: Do you not know that $\sin$ function is bounded by 1?

Comment: Because $-1\leq\sin\alpha\leq1$ is true for *any* $\alpha$.

Comment: Because -1 <= sin(y) <=1 for all Real y (the sine function only takes values between -1 and 1). Let y = 1/x

Answer (score 1):

$ \sin(x)$ or $ \sin(1/x) $ or $ \sin (f(x)) $ is bounded within limits $ \pm 1. $

So x^2 |$ \pm $ 1| tends to 0 as x $ \Rightarrow $ 0.